# Wireless HDMI from camera to mixer?

Tags: hdmi, wireless

I would like to stream video from a camera through its HDMI output to a mixer.
Extensive googling has only turned up solutions for streaming from PC's and phones onto a screen.

What I need is a dongle that plugs into the HDMI output of the camera, and transmits the video to a reciever.

The transmitter will need to be fairly small and not need mains power, as the point of having the wireless link is to be able to move the camera anywhere within a 30 meter range. The reciever can be any size and run off any power source.

Does such a product exist? Can anyone suggest one that is no more than £200?

EDIT:
Based on the answers I've recieved, I'd like to add a few points to explain why I want this particular solution;

- The venue is more or less circular, with a stage at the front, and
  about 400 seats, with four aisles between them. One camera is mounted
  to the wall on the right (when facing the stage), on the left of the
  far right aisle. The other is at the back, also mounted to the wall,
  and the third sits on a tripod on the right side of the room.
- Usually this is fine, but the angles of the cameras are far from
  perfect, and usually microphone stands or peoples heads get in the
  way. Also, we often want to get much closer to the stage and show
  things up close.
- We can't move a camera to the front of the venue near the stage as it
  would HAVE to be in the front row of seats (reasons are complicated,
  but boil down to stubborn organisers who absolutely cannot be
  reasoned with), and then it would be too low to get enough good shots
  to be worthwhile.
- The cameraman can't trail a long cable, not because of length
  limitations of HDMI (the cameras have SDI out) but because people are
  coming and going during events and it would present a trip hazard,
  not to mention only being able to move up and down the four aisles
  makes trailing a long cable annoying for the cameraman.
- The footage is being mixed and streamed online in realtime, so having
  a camera recording and then doing post production doesn't really
  help.

Streaming from the camera to the mixer is the best solution I've been able to come up with, but perhaps I've missed a much simpler option.

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: @DigiVisionMedia We're still using the same setup. Occasionally we can trail an SDI cable, but only for smaller events, and only in the front row of the venue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they exist. They are called HDMI wireless *extenders*. Sometimes they are called transmitters/receivers. No, the good ones are not cheap. Further, I don't know of any where the receiver does *not* need external power.

Here's two examples, a better one and a not so better one:

1. [IOGear Matrix pro](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1044925-REG/iogear_gwhdms52mb_wireless_5x2_hd_matrix.html) ([Here's a different offering](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815290061&cm_re=wireless_hdmi_transmitter_and_receiver-_-15-290-061-_-Product))
2. [Gefan Long Range Extender](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1163147-REG/gefen_ext_whd_1080p_lr_long_range_wireless_extender.html)

I have no experience with either product and practically none with wireless HDMI as a whole. Personally, I would *always* use a wire for something like video. If you're only going 30 feet, it's really not a big deal to have a wire, and HDMI can go 30 feet just fine. If you need more distance, there's extenders of various *wired* variety that I would prefer over wireless options.

---

From your comment below, it sounds like you are wanting to move throughout the event, therefore making a wireless solution optimal, allowing you to move about on your whim.

If you do not have to stream the feed to the internet, I suggest that instead of running your video wirelessly, run the audio only. Get yourself a wireless audio transmitter and receiver, then carry the receiver around with you and the camera, plugging in the audio receiver to your camera. There are literally thousands of options and should be easy to find with google. Alternatively, get a standalone audio recorder and then mix the audio and video together in post.

The downside of these methods is that you must record to the camera's internal media and it may increase your post production time. The upside is that you're mobile while recording.

Comment: Yes, question, why do you "need" wireless? There are sdi converters and fiber converters that go miles. Being wired is super reliable during production. While being wireless is a romantic idea, it's not the best approach.

Comment: @A.J.Hernandez I would like to be able to move the camera anywhere within a venue that is about 25 square meters. The venue has about 400 seats, with people coming and going during events, so trailing a long cable is not an ideal solution.

Comment: @RyanKrage In that case, yes, perhaps you need a wireless connection, but unless you need to stream to the internet, I think I have a better solution for you. I will make an edit.

Comment: @RyanKrage Edit made. Of note, I don't know of any wireless HDMI receivers that do not require an external power source.

Answer (score 1):

[Nitero](http://www.nitero.com/) Is looking to create a wireless solution for VR by the end of this year, which very well may apply to what you need as well. At the very least, if this technology does get off the ground we may see higher fidelity wireless solutions for video be produced off the back of this technology in the coming months/years. Basically, it might be worth waiting a bit to see what pans out, or you can use any of the solutions fredsbend pointed out.

Comment: I think eventually, wireless video capture *will* be a reliable and quality option. We certainly all hope so. Like AJ said previously, however, right now, it is a romantic idea. We are enamored by wireless, automagical options.

Comment: There are wireless sdi transmitters, but those are pricey. Why not have multiple cameras and then use a switcher to get different coverage around the venue? Your cameras can still "move" but not around the entire room, hence multiple camera spots.

Comment: @A.J.Hernandez That's the setup we currently have - two cameras at either side and one at the back. However, two are fixed to the walls and can't be moved, and the angles with the current setup aren't great. It would be great to be able to move at least one anywhere in the venue to get better shots, although I think we'll have to settle for relocating the one on a tripod until the price of the technology drops.

Answer (score 1):

Cerevo Liveshell 2. It,s battery powered also. As receiving-end use a laptop with vlc player. Hdmi from laptop to mixer. I used this setup a few times.